# How to prevent users from setting sensitive fields from form submissions in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I take an example from Rails Tutorial about "Follow a user".

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This line: `f.hidden_field :followed_id`

is generated into something like this in the browser:

`<input type="hidden" value="13">`

'13' indicates the `ID` of a user who is going to be followed.

Perhaps not all of my website users are tech savvy, but some users may found a way to do some tricks, e.g by opening the Firebug and simply edit the html input tag and set the value with random number.

It is clearly fast and simple to make a user to follow another user through the following way in my controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
  current_user.follow!(@user)        
end
```

Also, I need the attribute in my model to be accessible:

`attr_accessible :followed_id`

However, isn't it too dangerous to let this kind of data being manipulated easily by users? Is there any other solution instead of doing like the codes above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fine. If there are any cases where the user can tamper with data in a malicious way, you need to have some sort of server-side check. If the user may only follow certain other users, for example, then you need to check that they haven't tampered with that variable to follow a user that they aren't allowed to. It depends on the situation.

As a rule of thumb, data that comes from the user should not be considered trustworthy. Always assume that it may be tampered with. However, if they cannot tamper with it in a way that serves a malicious purpose (I.e. If users may follow any other user), then don't worry about it.